# Loading bundle without progress bar in metro bundle, only uccurs when build in real device, virtual device is welll

Tags: react-native

bundle is loaded but no progressbar
Enviroment: react-native 0.57.8, xcode:10.1, ios:12
 i built in xcode, npm start successfully, bundle is loaded but no progressbar in metro bundle.i run command:'react-native bundle" and show a error: "error: option '--entry-file' missing".